# How to reset user password by wordpress rest api

Tags: wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

Any one of you know know to send a reset link for lost password by wordpress rest api ? I have been looking into wordpress rest api documentation but I haven't find out anything about it. Maybe someone has done a custom function for that.

Answer (score 2):

I found out a way to do that:

```
function runRetrivePassword($data)
{
    global $wpdb, $wp_hasher;
    $user_data = get_user_by('email',  $data['email']);
    if (!$user_data) return array('result' => false);

    do_action('lostpassword_post');
    $user_login = $user_data->user_login;
    $user_email = $user_data->user_email;
    $key = get_password_reset_key($user_data);
    $message = __('Someone requested that the password be reset for the following account:') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= network_home_url('/') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __('If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __('To reset your password, visit the following address:') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login');

    if (is_multisite())
        $blogname = $GLOBALS['current_site']->site_name;
    else
        $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

    $title = sprintf(__('[%s] Password Reset'), $blogname);
    $title = apply_filters('retrieve_password_title', $title);
    $message = apply_filters('retrieve_password_message', $message, $key);
    if ($message && !wp_mail($user_email, $title, $message))
        wp_die(__('The e-mail could not be sent.') . "<br />\n" . __('Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function...'));

    return array('result' => true);
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('apiuser/v1', '/forgotpwd/(?P<email>\S+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'runRetrivePassword'
    ));
});
```